# How to find the symmetry group of the differential equation

Tags: cv.complex-variables, differential-equations, symmetry

I'm studying the following differential equation

$$
x \frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3} P[h, x]  
= \left (x^3 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3} +
 3x^2 h \frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^2 \partial h}  +
     3x h^2 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial x \partial h^2}  +
     h^3 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial h^3}\right )P[h, x]
$$
Obviously, this equation is invariant under following transformation
$$
P[h, x] \rightarrow P[- i h/x, 1/x]
$$
I'm interested in finding the full symmetry group of this equation.
Could it be possible to treat solutions of this equation as a function that lives on the complex plane with variable $z= h+i x$? Or is it possible to consider $h$ and $x$ as separate complex variables?

Answer (score 3):

The book by Willi-Hans Steeb, *Continuous Symmetries, Lie Algebras, Differential Equations and Computer Algebra*, (World Scientific, 2007) explains how to calculate symmetry groups for differential equations.

I suggest this rather than the better known books of L. Ovsjannikov, G. Bluman and P. Olver because of the inclusion of computer algebra. (The calculations to produce the symmetry group are easy, but are extensive and extremely tedious.)